# Find index of removed unique pairs

Tags: r, indexing, unique

I have a data frame of 2 columns and a vector of the same length. I am trying to remove all duplicated pairs in the data frame and at the same index, remove it from the vector.

I have a data frame:

```
> from <- c(1,1,2,4,3)
> to <- c(1,1,2,3,5)
> ft <- data.frame(from,to)
> ft
 from to
1    1  1
2    1  1
3    2  2
4    4  3
5    3  5
```

And vector:

```
> dist <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
> dist
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

I used the function `unique()` to remove all duplicated pairs:

```
> unique(ft)
  from to
1    1  1
3    2  2
4    4  3
5    3  5
```

How can I get the index of where every pair from "ft" has been removed so that I can remove it from "dist" which would be the 2 in this case.

Comment: `which(duplicated(ft))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @eddi notes, you can get a logical vector that indicates which rows are duplicates with `duplicated()`.  I combined that with `which()`, which returns the number associated with the logical that is `TRUE` (i.e., the duplicated row).  You can then create a new `data.frame` (`vector`, etc.) by using `-` to not include the indicated rows in the subscript of your object.

*Edit*:  In the comments, @DWin points out a better way than using `-`.  If we negate the `duplicated()` function with `!`, we will get a vector that we can use to determine which rows to *retain*:

```
> from <- c(1,1,2,4,3)
> to <- c(1,1,2,3,5)
> ft <- data.frame(from,to)
> ft
  from to
1    1  1
2    1  1
3    2  2
4    4  3
5    3  5
> dist <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
> dist
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> remove <- !duplicated(ft)
> remove
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> ft.new <- ft[which(remove), ]
> ft.new
  from to
1    1  1
3    2  2
4    4  3
5    3  5
> dist.new <- dist[which(remove)]
> dist.new
[1] 1 3 4 5
```

Comment: -which() is a dangerous contruction. Try in a situation where there are no rows that match: `from <- c(1,1,2,4,3); to <- c(1,1.1,2,3,5)`... `ft.new  #
[1] from to  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`. Construct a `subset` or use `!duplicated()`